# add dynamic onclick="location.href= to button via js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a working site with a working modal popup built with jquery. On this site there is a table with a column "delete". Every row has a href which opens the modal popup and in this popup there is a a href link "DELETE". This href link is filled dynamically by js code, depending on which delete column link was clicked on the site:

```
<td><span id="hoverdeleteTI" data-href="deleteTI.php?id=2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">OPEN POPUP</span></td>
```

The following script adds the href part to a href inside the modal popup.

```
<script>
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
$(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));

$('.debug-url').html('delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
});
</script>
```

Modal popup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="head-deletepopup">
                <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                <div class="mpopup-titel">DELETE CONFIRM</div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>REALLY?</p>
                <p class="debug-url"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="ddeletebutt btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
                <button type="button" class="ddeletebutt btn-ok">DELETE BUTTON</button>
                <a class="dddeletebutt btn-ok">DELETE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script converts this part `<a class="dddeletebutt btn-ok">DELETE</a>`
into `<a class="dddeletebutt btn-ok" href="deleteTI.php?id=2">DELETE</a>`

That's the part which is working. But what I actually want is, that it adds the href to the button before "DELETE BUTTON". Therefore I need to transcode this code `<button type="button" class="ddeletebutt btn-ok">DELETE BUTTON</button>` 
into 
`<button type="button" class="ddeletebutt" onclick="location.href='deleteTI.php?id=2'">DELETE BUTTON</button>`

But at the moment I obviously only getting: `<button type="button" class="ddeletebutt btn-ok" href="deleteTI.php?id=2">DELETE BUTTON</button>`

How can I change the added **href=** into **onclick="location.href=**

Thank you!

Comment: My take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kx7r2dht/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
$(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
```

To this:

```
$(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('onclick', 'location.href=\'' + $(e.relatedTarget).data('href') + '\'');
```

Comment: While this takes the OP's question at face value, it completely misses the opportunity to avoid the inline code route.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is targeting the anchor element instead of your button then use a better selector for finding the element. In your case prefix your class selector with a tag selector ie `button.btn_ok`

```
$(this).find('button.btn_ok')
```

Also you don't need to set the actual html onclick attribute, you can use jQuery event methods, or the native addEventListener

```
let href = $(e.relatedTarget).data('href');
$(this).find('button.btn_ok').click(()=>location.href=href});
//or with native methods
this.querySelector('button.btn_ok').addEventListener('click',()=>location.href=href});
```

And by your example your end element would not have the btn_ok class any more which you can remove by using jQuery's `removeClass()`

```
$(this).find('button.btn_ok').removeClass('btn_ok');
```